# Validate Custom Email Domains with Django-Registration

Tags: django, django-registration

I saw a version of JQuery EDU validation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686537/jquery-form-validation-only-allow-edu-email-addresses) but I'd love to use `django-registraion` to check a full domain `@someschool.edu` or `@alumni.someschool.edu`

Any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure of how to validate domain, but you can verify emails: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own form in forms.py, you already have some example for :

- registration with term of service
- registration with unique mail
- registration without freeemail

In your case add :

```
class RegistrationFormEduMail(RegistrationForm):

    good_domains = ['edu']

    def clean_email(self):

        email_domain = self.cleaned_data['email'].split('.')[-1]
        if email_domain not in self.good_domains:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Registration using non edu email addresses is prohibited. Please supply a different email address."))
        return self.cleaned_data['email']
```

Then go in registration/backends/default/**init**.py and import your form, change the name of the form returned by get_form_class() method to the name of your form (here: RegistrationFormEduMail)